# ModelForm Rendered on HTML not Submitting to Database

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, modelform

I have been struggling fr the past couple of days with this problem. My model form is not submitting. The data keeps appearing on html(where it is rendered after clicking the submit button without submitting. I also checked the database and noticed it's not been saved.

views.py

```
def add_logbook(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        inventory = InventoryForm(request.POST)
        if inventory.is_valid():
            inventory.cleaned_data.get('entry_date')
            updated_date = inventory.cleaned_data.get('updated_date')
            file_no = inventory.cleaned_data.get('file_no')
            case_no = inventory.cleaned_data.get('case_no')
            court = inventory.cleaned_data.get('court')
            court_no = inventory.cleaned_data.get('court_no')
            male_suspect = inventory.cleaned_data.get('male_suspect')
            female_suspect = inventory.cleaned_data.get('female_suspect')
            male_underage_suspect = inventory.cleaned_data.get('male_underage_suspect')
            female_underage_suspect = inventory.cleaned_data.get('female_underage_suspect')
            assigned_to = inventory.cleaned_data.get('assigned_to')
            agency = inventory.cleaned_data.get('agency')
            inventory.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Data Submited')
    else:
        inventory = InventoryForm()

    data = {'invt':inventory}

    return render(request, 'add-logbook.html', data)
```

The modelForm
forms.py

```
class InventoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    AGENCY_CHOICE = [
        ('CA', ' Choose Agency'),
        ('NCS', 'NCS'),
        ('PL', 'Police'),
        ('DSS', 'DSS'),
        ('OT', 'Others'),
    ]


    file_no = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'File Number'}))
    case_no = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Case Number'}))
    court = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Court'}))
    court_no = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Court Number'}))
    male_suspect = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
        'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Suspect'}))
    female_suspect = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
        'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Suspect'}))
    male_underage_suspect = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
        'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Suspect'}))
    female_underage_suspect = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
        'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Suspect'}))
    assigned_to = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Name'}))
    agency = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={
        'class':'form-control'}, choices=AGENCY_CHOICE))

    class Meta():
        model = InventoryModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

The Model Linked to the Form
models.py

```
class InventoryModel(models.Model):
    NCS = 'NS'
    POLICE = 'PL'
    DSS = 'DS'
    OTHERS = 'OT'
    AGENCY_CHOICE = [
        (NCS, 'NCS'),
        (POLICE, 'Police'),
        (DSS, 'DSS'),
        (OTHERS, 'Others'),
    ]


    # CASE DETAILS
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    file_no = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    case_no = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    court = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    court_no = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    male_suspect = models.IntegerField()
    female_suspect = models.IntegerField()
    male_underage_suspect = models.IntegerField()
    female_underage_suspect = models.IntegerField()
    assigned_to = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    agency = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=AGENCY_CHOICE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.file_no
```